# Pass Global JS Variable to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope

I have a page on my site that allows the user to select a client using a SELECT field.  When the client is selected, I have a JS/AJAX function which loads the client's uploaded pictures into bootstrap wells.  This all works great.

Before the javascript which loads the images I define a global variable called "clientid" and in the javascript I assign a value to the variable (the database-called numeric id for the client).

At the end of the loaded pictures a jquery file upload box appears where the user can add additional files to the client's account.  The script requires the global variable "clientid" in order to work as the file upload sends a $_POST value to the serverside script.

Since the jquery file upload is a document.ready function, I am unsure how to pass the global variable into it, since the global variable isn't given a value until AFTER the page load and AFTER the user selects a client.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code for the page:

```
<?php
$sql = $db->query("SELECT c_id, last_name, first_name FROM pan_clients WHERE client_status != 9 ORDER BY last_name ASC");
?>
<link href="http://hayageek.github.io/jQuery-Upload-File/4.0.10/uploadfile.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://hayageek.github.io/jQuery-Upload-File/4.0.10/jquery.uploadfile.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var clientid = '';
function selectClient(svalue)
{
     clientid = svalue;
     $.ajax({
          url: 'http://<?php echo $_SESSION['sitevars']['siteurl'] ?>/js/ajax_query.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
               'get_docs':true,
               'client_id':svalue
          },
          success: function(data) {
               document.getElementById("hidden_panel").style.display = "block";
               document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = data;
          }
     });     
}
</script>
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">Select a Client to view documents.</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="col-lg-4">
<label>Select a Client:</label>
<select name="c_id" id="c_id" class="form-control" onchange="selectClient(this.value)">
<option value="">Select</option>
<?php
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     echo '<option value="'. $row['c_id'] .'">'. $row['last_name'] .', '. $row['first_name'] .'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8"></div><br />
<hr /><br />
<div id="hidden_panel" class="col-lg-12" style="display: none;">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">Saved Documents</div>
<div class="panel-body" id="results">


</div>
</div>
<div class="row">

<div id="fileuploader">Upload</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
          url:"http://<?php echo $_SESSION['sitevars']['siteurl'] ?>/js/ajax_query.php",
          multiple:true,
          dragDrop:true,
          formData: {"c_id":clientid},
          fileName:"client_files",
          acceptFiles:"image/*",
          showPreview:true,
          previewHeight: "100px",
          previewWidth: "100px"          
    });
});
</script>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If i get you right, I think you will need to ask the user to select the client before initialize the upload widget anyway. If it depends on user's action, you can't do nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my approach a little bit.  Instead of making the file upload script a $(document).ready() function, I just turned it into a regular called function.  This way I can send the needed variable into it on successful completion of the selectClient() function.  Works like a charm!:

```
<?php
$sql = $db->query("SELECT c_id, last_name, first_name FROM pan_clients WHERE client_status != 9 ORDER BY last_name ASC");
?>
<link href="http://hayageek.github.io/jQuery-Upload-File/4.0.10/uploadfile.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://hayageek.github.io/jQuery-Upload-File/4.0.10/jquery.uploadfile.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function selectClient(svalue)
{
     $.ajax({
          url: 'http://<?php echo $_SESSION['sitevars']['siteurl'] ?>/js/ajax_query.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
               'get_docs':true,
               'client_id':svalue
          },
          success: function(data) {
               document.getElementById("hidden_panel").style.display = "block";
               document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = data;
               runUploader(svalue);
          }
     });     
}
</script>
<script>
function deleteImage(imageid)
{
     $.ajax({
          url: 'http://<?php echo $_SESSION['sitevars']['siteurl'] ?>/js/ajax_query.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
               'delete_file':true,
               'file_id':imageid
          },
          success: function(data) {
               document.getElementById("well" + imageid).style.display = "none";
          }
     });      
}
</script>
<script>
function assignType(imageid, filetype)
{
     $.ajax({
          url: 'http://<?php echo $_SESSION['sitevars']['siteurl'] ?>/js/ajax_query.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
               'change_file_type':true,
               'file_id':imageid,
               'filetype':filetype
          }
     });         
}
</script>
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">Select a Client to view documents.</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="col-lg-4">
<label>Select a Client:</label>
<select name="c_id" id="c_id" class="form-control" onchange="selectClient(this.value)">
<option value="">Select</option>
<?php
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     echo '<option value="'. $row['c_id'] .'">'. $row['last_name'] .', '. $row['first_name'] .'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8"></div><br />
<hr /><br />
<div id="hidden_panel" class="col-lg-12" style="display: none;">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">Saved Documents</div>
<div class="panel-body" id="results">


</div>
</div>
<div class="row">

<div id="fileuploader">Upload</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
function runUploader(clientid)
{
    $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
          url:"http://<?php echo $_SESSION['sitevars']['siteurl'] ?>/js/ajax_query.php",
          multiple:true,
          dragDrop:true,
          formData: {"c_id":clientid},
          fileName:"client_files",
          acceptFiles:"image/*",
          showPreview:true,
          previewHeight: "100px",
          previewWidth: "100px"          
    });
}
</script>
</div>
</div>
```